# How to prevent squid from caching and just filter?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid, filter

I have set a proxy server on my network. I only want to filter the web traffic. So, I have Squid as a proxy and Qlproxy as the filter : http://www.quintolabs.com/qlicap_info.php

My server have only about 640MB of RAM... So, Squid cache frequently. So, need to disable caching!

How can I disable caching and let Squid forward everything to the filter without touching them?

Thanks...

PS : Im using Squid3! Is there an alternative to web filtering?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can set `cache deny all` in your squid.conf to disable caching for everyone using the proxy.

Comment: That will prevent everyone from surfing the web no.... It will deny access!

Comment: No, it denys caching of objects and retrieval of objects from the cache. http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.HEAD/cfgman/cache.html

Comment: I also have a problem like this... while downloading big apps... The download speed drops to 0kbps and then it come again when i pause and restart it! Is it possible to let it skip big files?

Comment: Thanks bro... it looks like the issue is solved :D But im not sure about the speed drop.... Need to wait and see... Have any idea about it?

Comment: According to this: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#Can_I_make_Squid_proxy_only.2C_without_caching_anything.3F this only works for Squid 3.1 and above, or Squid 2.7

Comment: @AsfandYarQazi Which version of squid was in use 4 years ago ?