# how to make squid work like proxy only, without caching anything

Tags: squid, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent squid from caching and just filter?](https://serverfault.com/questions/356137/how-to-prevent-squid-from-caching-and-just-filter)

I want to make squid work purely as a proxy, so that it does not cache anything.

Is such a usage of squid possible? How do I do this?

I am using v3.1 of Squid on Cent OS 6.2- x86 edition.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is straight out of the [Squid FAQ](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ConfiguringSquid#Can_I_make_Squid_proxy_only.2C_without_caching_anything.3F):

> **Can I make Squid proxy only, without caching anything?**
>
> Sure, there are few things you can do.
>
> You can use the cache access list to make Squid never cache any
>   response:
>
> ```
> cache deny all
> ```
>
> With Squid-2.7, Squid-3.1 and later you can also remove
>   all 'cache_dir' options from your squid.conf to avoid having a cache
>   directory.
>
> With Squid-2.4, 2.5, 2.6, and 3.0 you need to use the "null" storage
>   module:
>
> ```
> cache_dir null /tmp
> ```
>
> Note: a null cache_dir does not disable caching,
>   but it does save you from creating a cache structure if you have
>   disabled caching with cache. The directory (e.g., /tmp) must exist so
>   that squid can chdir to it, unless you also use the coredump_dir
>   option.
>
> To configure Squid for the "null" storage module, specify it on the
>   configure command line:
>
> ```
> --enable-storeio=null,...
> ```